# How to patch class with different class in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch

I'm trying to patch one class with another one in tests, doing:

```
@patch('integrations.Client', 'tests.utils.MockClient')
def test_client(self):
    check_client()
```

method:

```
check_client()
```

is using `__integrations.Client__` class, but unfortunately after doing `@patch` inside `__check_client__` class is not replaced with `__tests.utils.MockClient__`

Answer (score 1):

I just had to use patch with **spec=True**

```
@patch(...., spec=True)
```